# create a 3d binary mask in numpy with a 2d array of depth values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking

I would like to create a 3d mask array based on a 2d array of 'depths' that indicate the extent to which the third dimension is filled with ones. I had hoped there would've been a vectorized solution to this within numpy rather than resorting to for loops.
For example:

```
tst = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3,3) # depths referred to above

blk = np.zeros(shape=(3,3,9)) # the output 3d array to be filled with ones or zeros
```

The intended results at the following example positions would be:

```
blk[0,0]
array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
blk[1,2]
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.])
blk[2,2]
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Does anyone have any ideas/hints on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use broadcasting, comparing to [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
blk = (tst[..., None] > np.arange(tst.max())[None, None]).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],     # blk[0, 0]
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]],    # blk[1, 2]

       [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]])   # blk[2, 2]
```